# Connect Bluetooth LE device using Arduino Nano 33 BLE board

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-esp32, arduino-nano

i want to use Arduino Nano 33 BLE board to connect to bluetooth LE device.
From Android App (Serial Terminal) i know:

- Device Name
- Device MAC
- Service UUID
- Read Characteristic UUID
- Write Characteristic UUID

I have tried to use and modify the code as described here:
https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/nano-33-ble-sense/ble-device-to-device/

But finally i was not successful.

Which of above information is mandatory to establish connection to BT LE device via Nano 33 BLE board?
Any android code availalbe to establish connection to BT LE device and send command after connection is successfully established?

Thanks for support.
Br
Chris

I tried to followed instruction on arduino.com but was not successful.
Also chatcpt could not help to get functional code.